# Marking an email as Unread when moved to a folder in Exchange

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm in the process of building an application that uses Outlook/Exchange as a psudo workflow system and monitors certain folders for new mails.

As part of this, users will manually move email messages between public folders in Exchange (different folders will represent different steps in a business process).

I'd like to be able to monitor when a mail is moved into a particular folder and automatically mark it was unread when this happens. I think I can do this by monitoring the folder using Exchange Web Services, but I can this be done with an Exchange rule (set up either manually or programmatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Rules only work on the Inbox Folder so you need a process that monitors the folder continuously and does the update. If your using Office365 then one option of doing that is to use Flow which should work okay for that.